# Test JwtDecoder in @WebMvcTest with Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-test

I am using Spring Boot 2.2.1 with `spring-security-oauth2-resource-server:5.2.0.RELEASE`. I want to write an integration test to test the security is ok.

I have this `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` defined in my application:

```
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.resource.OAuth2ResourceServerProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.oauth2.server.resource.OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.DelegatingOAuth2TokenValidator;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.OAuth2Error;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.OAuth2TokenValidator;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.OAuth2TokenValidatorResult;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.Jwt;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtDecoder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtValidators;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.NimbusJwtDecoder;

@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final OAuth2ResourceServerProperties properties;
    private final SecuritySettings securitySettings;

    public WebSecurityConfiguration(OAuth2ResourceServerProperties properties, SecuritySettings securitySettings) {
        this.properties = properties;
        this.securitySettings = securitySettings;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api/**")
            .authenticated()
            .and()
            .oauth2ResourceServer(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer::jwt);
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtDecoder jwtDecoder() {
        NimbusJwtDecoder result = NimbusJwtDecoder.withJwkSetUri(properties.getJwt().getJwkSetUri())
                                                  .build();

        OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt> validator = new DelegatingOAuth2TokenValidator<>(
                JwtValidators.createDefault(),
                new AudienceValidator(securitySettings.getApplicationId()));

        result.setJwtValidator(validator);
        return result;
    }

    private static class AudienceValidator implements OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt> {

        private final String applicationId;

        public AudienceValidator(String applicationId) {
            this.applicationId = applicationId;
        }

        @Override
        public OAuth2TokenValidatorResult validate(Jwt token) {
            if (token.getAudience().contains(applicationId)) {
                return OAuth2TokenValidatorResult.success();
            } else {
                return OAuth2TokenValidatorResult.failure(
                        new OAuth2Error("invalid_token", "The audience is not as expected, got " + token.getAudience(),
                                        null));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It has a custom validator to check the audience (`aud`) claim in the token.

I currently have this test, which works, but it does not check the audience claim at all:

```
@WebMvcTest(UserController.class)
@EnableConfigurationProperties({SecuritySettings.class, OAuth2ResourceServerProperties.class})
@ActiveProfiles("controller-test")
class UserControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    void testOwnUserDetails() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/api/users/me")
                                .with(jwt(createJwtToken())))
               .andExpect(status().isOk())
               .andExpect(jsonPath("userId").value("AZURE-ID-OF-USER"))
               .andExpect(jsonPath("name").value("John Doe"));
    }

    @Test
    void testOwnUserDetailsWhenNotLoggedOn() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/api/users/me"))
               .andExpect(status().isUnauthorized());
    }

    @NotNull
    private Jwt createJwtToken() {
        String userId = "AZURE-ID-OF-USER";
        String userName = "John Doe";
        String applicationId = "AZURE-APP-ID";

        return Jwt.withTokenValue("fake-token")
                  .header("typ", "JWT")
                  .header("alg", "none")
                  .claim("iss",
                         "https://b2ctestorg.b2clogin.com/80880907-bc3a-469a-82d1-b88ffad655df/v2.0/")
                  .claim("idp", "LocalAccount")
                  .claim("oid", userId)
                  .claim("scope", "user_impersonation")
                  .claim("name", userName)
                  .claim("azp", applicationId)
                  .claim("ver", "1.0")
                  .subject(userId)
                  .audience(Set.of(applicationId))
                  .build();
    }
}
```

I also have a properties file for the `controller-test` profile that contains the application id and the jwt-set-uri:

```
security-settings.application-id=FAKE_ID
spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.jwk-set-uri=https://b2ctestorg.b2clogin.com/b2ctestorg.onmicrosoft.com/discovery/v2.0/keys?p=b2c_1_ropc_flow
```

Maybe the JwtDecoder is not used because the Jwt is created manually? How could I make sure the JwtDecoder is called in the test?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By using the JWT post processor `.with(jwt(createJwtToken())))` you are able to bypass the `JwtDecoder`.

Consider what would happen if the `JwtDecoder` was not bypassed.
In the filter chain, your request would reach a point where the `JwtDecoder` parses the JWT value.
In this case the value is `"fake-token"`, which will result in an exception because it is not a valid JWT.
This means the code will not even reach the point where `AudienceValidator` is called.

You can think of the value passed into `SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors.jwt(Jwt jwt)` as the response that would be returned from `JwtDecoder.decode(String token)`.
Then, the tests using `SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors.jwt(Jwt jwt)` will test the behaviour when a valid JWT token is provided.
You can add additional tests for the `AudienceValidator` to ensure that it is functioning correctly.

Comment: I just recognized your response. I have a bit similar issue about it but I couldn't fix it. Can you help me ? Here is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74378611/spring-boot-microservices-junit-controller-test-jwt-issue

Answer (score 7):

To elaborate on the answer from Eleftheria Stein-Kousathana, this is what I changed to make it possible:

1) Create a `JwtDecoderFactoryBean` class to be able to unit test the `JwtDecoder` and the configured validators:

```
@Component
public class JwtDecoderFactoryBean implements FactoryBean<JwtDecoder> {

    private final OAuth2ResourceServerProperties properties;
    private final SecuritySettings securitySettings;
    private final Clock clock;

    public JwtDecoderFactoryBean(OAuth2ResourceServerProperties properties,
                                 SecuritySettings securitySettings,
                                 Clock clock) {
        this.properties = properties;
        this.securitySettings = securitySettings;
        this.clock = clock;
    }


    @Override
    public JwtDecoder getObject() {
        JwtTimestampValidator timestampValidator = new JwtTimestampValidator();
        timestampValidator.setClock(clock);
        JwtIssuerValidator issuerValidator = new JwtIssuerValidator(securitySettings.getJwtIssuer());
        JwtAudienceValidator audienceValidator = new JwtAudienceValidator(securitySettings.getJwtApplicationId());
        OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt> validator = new DelegatingOAuth2TokenValidator<>(
                timestampValidator,
                issuerValidator,
                audienceValidator);

        NimbusJwtDecoder decoder = NimbusJwtDecoder.withJwkSetUri(properties.getJwt().getJwkSetUri())
                                                   .build();

        decoder.setJwtValidator(validator);
        return decoder;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getObjectType() {
        return JwtDecoder.class;
    }
}
```

I also extracted the `AudienceValidator` from the original code to an external class and renamed it to `JwtAudienceValidator`.

2) Remove the `JwtDecoder` `@Bean` method from the security configuration so it looks like this:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api/**")
            .authenticated()
            .and()
            .oauth2ResourceServer(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer::jwt);
    }
}
```

3) Create a `Clock` bean in some `@Configuration` class:

```
    @Bean
    public Clock clock() {
        return Clock.systemDefaultZone();
    }
```

(This is needed for unit testing of time expiry of tokens)

With this setup, it is now possible to write a unit test for the `JwtDecoder` setup that is the actual setup the application uses:

```
   // actual @Test methods ommitted, but they can use this private method
   // to setup a JwtDecoder and test some valid/invalid JWT tokens.

@NotNull
    private JwtDecoder createDecoder(String currentTime, String issuer, String audience) {
        OAuth2ResourceServerProperties properties = new OAuth2ResourceServerProperties();
        properties.getJwt().setJwkSetUri(
                "https://mycompb2ctestorg.b2clogin.com/mycompb2ctestorg.onmicrosoft.com/discovery/v2.0/keys?p=b2c_1_ropc_flow");

        JwtDecoderFactoryBean factoryBean = new JwtDecoderFactoryBean(properties,
                                                                      new SecuritySettings(audience, issuer),
                                                                      Clock.fixed(Instant.parse(currentTime),
                                                                                  ZoneId.systemDefault()));
        //noinspection ConstantConditions - getObject never returns null in this case
        return factoryBean.getObject();
    }
```

Finally, the `@WebMvcTest` needs to have a mock `JwtDecoder` since the real one is not started anymore with the `@WebMvcTest` test slice (due to the use of the factory bean). This is good IMO as otherwise, I needed to define properties for the real `JwtDecoder` that did not get used anyway. As a consequence, I don't need the `controller-test` profile anymore in the test.

So just declare a field like this:

```
@MockBean
private JwtDecoder jwtDecoder;
```

or create a nested test configuration class:

```
 @TestConfiguration
    static class TestConfig {
        @Bean
        public JwtDecoder jwtDecoder() {
            return mock(JwtDecoder.class);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that either the mockMvc has not been configured to take the security aspect into account (1), or the `@WebMvcTest` [test slice](https://spring.io/blog/2016/08/30/custom-test-slice-with-spring-boot-1-4) does not auto-configure all the required beans (2).

1: Could you try adding adding `@AutoConfigureMockMvc` to the class, or configuring the mockMvc manually using

```java
@Autowired
private WebApplicationContext context; 

private MockMvc mockMvc;

@Before
public void setup() {
mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
                .webAppContextSetup(context)
                .apply(springSecurity())
                .build();
}
```

2: If it is related to the `@WebMvcTest` test slice, consider adding `@Import(WebSecurityConfig.class)` to the test class. Otherwise, use `@SpringBootTest` together with `@AutoConfigureMockMvc` on the test class instead of `@WebMvcTest` to set up a Spring Boot Test.

Comment: Thanks. I just tried your proposals, but it makes no difference. `@AutoConfigurationMockMvc` is surely not needed as the `@Autowired` on `MockMvc` would not have worked before.